# Cannot get Motorola MC3190 to associate with WiFi access point

Tags: wifi, embedded, windows-mobile, windows-ce

Using the Wireless Fusion management tools for the Symbol / Motorola MC3190, we cannot get the handheld to associate to the WiFi access point. Using the Find WLANs feature in the Fusion software, we can see that the device is detecting the access point, as it does show up in the list of detected WLANs. So since it can see the available WLANs, the radio / hardware is seemingly working just fine. The access point is using WPA2 AES for security and other devices have no problem associating to it. It is a non-Enterprise level access point, so the Security Mode selected in the Fusion WLAN profile is "WPA2 - Personal". The only clue it seems to provide is in the Log information in Fusion Wireless Status. In the log it is showing the message "Association timeout" about 10 seconds after the "Setting SSID:" message.

Comment: Are you sure the keys on both sides match *exactly*?

Comment: Certainly, double checked multiple times and had someone else try to recreate the profile just to have another set of eyes on it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is what I finally found:

To enable the MC31XX device to associate to the AP, go into the Fusion tool and select **Options**.

From the list of available options, select **Regulatory** from the dropdown.

Then **uncheck** the option **Enable 802.11d**.

Comment: Thank you, thank you. I've been trying to get my device to connect for days. This did the trick.

Comment: @dmarietta thanks ALOT dude.
cannot vote you up, credits problem :(
solution was exect and worked in first attempt. I waisted 2 days and thought wifi of my Motorolla MC3190 could be burned or something.. its working now. thanks again :)

Comment: If I could upvote you 1000 times I would. Thank you!!